# How to use selected .class from .jar

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am developing an API(.jar) to be used with Android App, I have constrain on size of .jar file after build.

I am using several dependent libraries(.jar) files, but not completely; hardly 5-6 class files from 200.

How can I use the selected .class files from libraries and dependent .class files?

Comment: Jar files are just Zip files.  You can use any Zip/Jar utility to unpack the .class files.

Answer (score 1):

Proguard automatically does this.
Configure proguard via Gradle: 
http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/gradle.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you are looking for but you can use `-cp` to run a specific class in your jar file

example:

```
java -cp myjar.jar package1.class1
```